# Where is `/var/www` in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd

I have installed Apache Web Server in Arch Linux. The Apache is working fine and when I typing localhost in my browser see this:

```
Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 PHP/5.5.7 Server at localhost Port 80
```

I can't find the `/var/www` directory and creating it can't solve the 404 error. Is there any equivalent for `/var/www` in Arch Linux?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The equivalent is in `/srv/http`. You can find some discussion about its use in Arch in [this](http://archlinux.2023198.n4.nabble.com/let-s-discuss-srv-again-td2037761.html) mailing list post and [this](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/16410) bug report (albeit only tangentially, those links discuss using it as a location for installed packages).

Comment: Or the generic method to find it out: search for `DocumentRoot` in the configuration file(s) (usually httpd.conf or conf/* in /etc/httpd/ or /etc/apache2/).